# Why std::remove takes const version of iterators?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to compile very simple code:

```
std::set<int> a{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::remove(a.begin(), a.end(), 3);
```

I expect this can't go wrong but I am surprised. Error emits:

```
Error   1   error C3892: '_Next' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm
```

How could this be? a is a non-const std::set. std::remove() moves the element of it and seems perfectly legal.

In VS 2008, below similar code compiles with no error:

```
std::set<int> a;
std::remove(a.begin(), a.end(), 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

The set is non-const but `set::begin()`, `set::end()` returns a const_iterator. As can be seen [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin).

I believe this is to avoid "outsiders" being able to swap elements around as one of set's invariants is that all elements are sorted (this is exactly what `std::remove` does, it moves elements around so that you can call erase on it afterwards, see [erase-remove idiom](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom))

If you want to remove an element use [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) member function.

Comment: Yes, I notice this behaviour. It is different from VS 2008. In VS 2008, the code compiles.

Comment: @Sheen this is a change in the C++ standard itself.

Comment: P.S. I'm not fond of the change. You used to be able to make an object with a key part, and as long as you didn't change the key you could modify the rest of the object as necessary. That's no longer allowed.

Comment: @MarkRansom - What change? All the compilers I use reject  `std::remove(a.begin(), a.end(), 3)`, regardless of the version of the standard I tell the compiler to compile against. I suspect it's more of a case that VS 2008 (a compiler I don't use) wasn't compliant with any version of the standard.

Comment: @DavidHammen I suppose it's possible that I'm remembering incorrectly. All I know is that I've used that pattern a couple of times and I was sorry to see it go.

Answer (score 0):

`std::remove` is intended for linear containers like `vector` and `list`, not sorted containers like `set`. (Consider: `remove` swaps elements. What would it even *mean* to swap elements of a `set`?)

It sounds like you want `std::set::erase`.